# How can I decrypt a file encrypted with the FreeBSD bdes(1) command using openssl?

Tags: encryption, freebsd, openssl

The file was encrypted using the FreeBSD bdes(1) command with the default parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $KEY contains the key used for the bdes(1) encryption, the following sequence does the job.

```
 HEXKEY=`echo -n $KEY | 
   dd conv=parodd | 
   od -t x1 2>/dev/null | 
   awk '{$1=""; print}' |
   sed 's/ //g'` 
 openssl enc -d -K $HEXKEY -iv 0 -des-cbc
```

One remaining problem, is that openssl complains when it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: Specify -n to echo, in order to avoid including a spurious newline in the key. Otherwise modern *openssl* versions issue an error message, `hex string is too long`, and fail to decrypt.

Comment: I corrected the command invocation.